# Azure DevOps Manual tests. Change step outcome

Tags: azure-devops

Running manual tests in Azure DevOps and I accidentally set one step to fail instead of pass. I can change the outcome of the entire test to pass, but the incorrect failure still shows in reports.  is there a way to change this? All I can find is "Update Analysis"

Thanks

Mark

Tried to change status of step

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Report data is updated approximately every 15 minutes. Do not use this report for real-time analysis or reporting. Expect ~15 mins of duration between a test execution and the same to show up in the report.

I tested your situation, the report data update later.

Please check if it works now.

For more information, you could refer to [progress report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/progress-report?view=azure-devops).